Desambiguar listas de parámetros variádicos
Tengo un objeto S cuyo constructor es privado y sólo se puede instanciar mediante un método factoría:
template <typename Object, typename Data>
struct S
{
    // Factoria
    template <typename ... A, typename ... B>
    static S create(const A &...a, const B &...b)
    {
        return S(new Object(a ...), new Data(b ...));
    }

private:

    using object_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Object>;
    using data_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Data>;

    object_ptr m_object{};
    data_ptr m_data{};

    // Constructor privado
    S(O *o, D *d) : m_object{o}, m_data{d} {};
};

Podemos ver que el método factoría recibe dos packs de parámetros, el primer pack se usa para construir uno de los sub-objetos de S y el segundo para construir otro de los sub-objetos.
Como cada uno de los sub-objetos es un parámetro de plantilla, no sabemos qué parámetros se usan para construirlos así que el compilador debe "adivinar" cómo repartir los parámetros del método factoría y eso asumía que sucedía, pero el siguiente código:
struct O { O(char, short, int) {} };
struct D { D(long, float, double) {} };

int main()
{
    const auto &s = S<O, D>::create('\0', short{1}, 2, 3l, .4f, .5);

    return 0;
}

Falla con este error:
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'O'
                return S(new Object(a ...), new Data(b ...));
                             ^
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'S<O, D>::create<, char, short, int, long, float, double>' requested here
        const auto &s = S<O, D>::create('\0', short{1}, 2, 3l, .4f, .5);
                                 ^
note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
struct O { O(char, short, int) {} };
       ^
note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 0 were provided
struct O { O(char, short, int) {} };

Podemos ver en la primera note que el compilador ha interpretado que el primer pack de parámetros está vacío mientras que el segundo recibe los seis parámetros:
                                                    Ningún parámetro ______
                                                                           \
                                                                            v
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'S<O, D>::create<, char, short, int, long, float, double>'
                                                                              \________________ __________________/
                                                                                               v 
                                                                                        Seis parámetros

¿De qué manera podría darle pistas al compilador de cómo repartir los pack de parámetros para que el método factoría funcione correctamente?

Lo que pides no es cosa menor.
El método al que he llegado es complejo y animo a cualquiera a que continue trabajando en él para obtener versiones más sencillas.
Verificar si una clase es construíble con un rango de una tupla
La idea principal es escribir create con un único paquete de parámetros y después ayudarnos de std::is_constructible_v para saber cuántos parámetros necesita el primero de los dos contructores.
Definimos una template que nos permita comprobar si una clase se puede construir con un rango de valores en una tupla:
template<typename T, typename Tuple, std::size_t Begin, std::size_t End>
bool constexpr es_construible() {
    return []<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) -> bool {
        return std::is_constructible_v<T, std::tuple_element_t<Begin + I, Tuple>...>;
    }(std::make_index_sequence<End - Begin>{});
}

Como estamos trabajando con el tipo de la tupla y no con una instancia de la tupla, usamos std::tuple_element_t en vez de decltype.
Hallar el punto de división en los argumentos para ambos constructores
Ahora comprobaremos si existe un N, con 0 ≤ N ≤ std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>, que nos sirva para separar los argumentos de ambos constructores.
Lo haremos con una recursividad de templates para que se resuelva en tiempo de compilación:
template <typename T, typename Q, typename Tuple, std::size_t N = 0>
struct constructor_arg_counter {

    // Comprobamos si tomando los N primeros argumentos podemos construir T
    static constexpr bool es_construibleT = es_construible<T, Tuple, 0, N>();

    // Comprobamos si tomando el resto de argumentos podemos construir Q
    static constexpr bool es_construibleQ = es_construible<Q, Tuple, N, std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>();
    
    // Inicializamos la "variable de retorno"
    // Si hemos conseguido inicializar T, ya sabemos que necesitamos los N primeros elementos de la tupla
    // Si ningún constructor de T puede ser llamado con los N primeros elementos de la tupla,
    // aumento un elemento más y continúo la recursión.
    static constexpr std::size_t value = 
        (es_construibleT && es_construibleQ) ? N
        : constructor_arg_counter<T, Q, Tuple, N + 1>::value;
};

// Este proceso se detendrá cuando N sea mayor que la longitud de la tupla.
// Es decir: ni siquiera tomando todos los elementos de la tupla podemos construir T
template <typename T, typename Q, typename Tuple>
struct constructor_arg_counter<T, Q, Tuple, std::tuple_size_v<Tuple> + 1> {
    // Doy un valor para poder acceder a value, pero no podremos usarlo
    static constexpr std::size_t value = std::tuple_size_v<Tuple> + 1;
};

Usamos la variable value como si fuera el valor de retorno de este cálculo.
Todas las variables que necesitemos declarar deberán ser estáticas.

El primer argumento de la template T es la clase que tratamos de construir (en nuestro caso Object) con los N primeros elementos de la tupla Tuple.
Análogamente Q es la clase que queremos contruir con el resto de argumentos de la tupla (en nuestro caso Data).
Tuple tendrá los tipos que hemos recibido en nuestra factoría. Como es una tupla y no un paquete de parámetros, tenemos que usar std::tuple_size_v en vez de sizeof....
N será nuestro contador, el que nos indique cuántos elementos de la tupla hemos probado ya.

El paso inicial de N es 0 porque podría ocurrir que Object no necesitara ningún argumento para ser construido.
Hemos escrito una especialización de constructor_arg_counter que detiene la recursividad cuando N es estrictamente mayor que la longitud de Tuple.
El hecho de que la desigualdad sea estricta nos cubre el caso en el que Data se pueda construir sin argumentos.
Nótese que estos métodos no necesitan para nada S: se pueden definir en un namespace anónimo fuera de la estructura.
Separar la tupla en el punto hallado
Ahora podemos separar los argumentos que recibe la factoría en dos tuplas.
Usaremos std::forward para no perder las referencias.
Podemos saber con qué categoría tenemos que hacer el forward gracias a std::tuple_element_t.
Por el mismo motivo usamos std::forward_as_tuple en vez de std::make_tuple.
Esta precaución hay que tenerla por si alguno de los dos constructores esperara una referencia l-value no constante o una referencia r-value.
template <std::size_t Begin, std::size_t End, typename Tuple>
auto constexpr subtuple(const Tuple& tuple)
{
    return [&tuple]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return std::forward_as_tuple(
            std::forward<std::tuple_element_t<Begin + I, Tuple>>(std::get<Begin + I>(tuple))...
        );
    }(std::make_index_sequence<End - Begin>{});
}

Llamada al constructor con la tupla
Del mismo modo para instanciar los dos objetos usaremos std::move al pasarle las tuplas a std::apply.
Si no lo hiciéramos, podríamos perder la condición de r-value y std::forward no se haría correctamente.
template <typename T, typename ArgsTuple>
T* newT(ArgsTuple&& args)
{
    return std::apply(
        [](auto&&... params) -> T* {
            return new T(std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...);
        }, std::move(args));
}

Tanto en subtuple como en newT usamos std::forward para evitar copiar los argumentos.
Si no esperamos recibir objetos de copia pesada, podemos evitar el std::forward y simplemente hacer el static_cast correspondiente.
Lo que no podemos evitar es respectivamente: std::forward_as_tuple y std::move.
Función factoría
Juntando todas la piezas:
template <typename... Args>
static S create(Args&&... args)
{
    // Convertimos los argumentos a una tupla para poder manejarlos con facilidad
    // En particular queremos acceder a ellos por índice
    auto args_tuple = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    // Contamos cuántos elementos de la tupla necesitamos para el primer constructor
    constexpr std::size_t n_args_Object = constructor_arg_counter<Object, Data, decltype(args_tuple)>::value;
    // Si no hemos conseguido encontrar cómo dividir la tupla,
    // este valor será demasiado grande y la compilación fallará
    static_assert(n_args_Object <= sizeof...(Args));

    // Definimos la primera tupla
    auto&& args_Object = subtuple<0, n_args_Object>(args_tuple);

    // Definimos la segunda tupla
    auto&& args_Data = subtuple<n_args_Object, sizeof...(Args)>(args_tuple);

    // Pasamos las tuplas a sus respectivos constructores y devolvemos la instancia de S
    return S(newT<Object>(args_Object),
             newT<Data>(args_Data));
}

De nuevo hemos usado std::forward_as_tuple en vez de std::make_tuple.

Si vas a ver el caso funcionante es interesante comprobar que si cambiamos el compilador y en vez de gcc usamos clang, el código no compila.
Podemos conseguir que compile con clang si escribimos esta otra versión:
template <typename T, typename Q, typename Tuple, std::size_t N = 0, typename Enable = void>
struct constructor_arg_counter { /**/ }

template <typename T, typename Q, typename Tuple, std::size_t N>
struct constructor_arg_counter<T, Q, Tuple, N, std::enable_if_t<(N > std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>)>> { /**/ }

Otra alternativa a std::enable_if sugerida por Mateo es usar concepts (a partir de C++20):
template <typename Tuple, std::size_t N>
concept ExcedeTupla = (N > std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>);

template <typename T, typename Q, typename Tuple, std::size_t N>
requires ExcedeTupla<Tuple, N>
struct constructor_arg_counter<T, Q, Tuple, N> { /**/ };

El motivo por el que me interesa poder compilar el código con clang es que consultar el resultado de CppInsights es muy ilustrativo.

Tal vez ese pueda simplificar con conceptos.

Pero si no me equivoco, los conceptos no pueden resolver el problema principal: que un argumento variádico absorberá todos los argumentos de la función ¿no?

Lo decía por el meta-programming. Los conceptos permiten simplificar cosas como enable_if

La respuesta de Jorge Luis es válida y buena aunque verbosa. Podemos obtener resultados parecidos con menos código usando otras aproximaciones:
Pasando dos tuplas a S::create:
En este caso, para hacer el código más simple y legible las tuplas son auto-deducidas:
template <typename object_t>
auto tuple_to(auto &&a_tuple)
{
    return std::apply([](auto &&...a_args_pack)
    {
        return std::make_unique<object_t>(std::forward<decltype(a_args_pack)>(a_args_pack) ...);
    }, std::forward<decltype(a_tuple)>(a_tuple));
}

struct O { O(char, short, int) {} };
struct D { D(long, float, double) {} };

template <typename Object, typename Data>
struct S
{
    // Factoria
    static S create(const auto &&a, const auto &&b)
    {
        return S(tuple_to<Object>(a), tuple_to<Data>(b));
    }

private:

    using object_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Object>;
    using data_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Data>;

    object_ptr m_object{};
    data_ptr m_data{};

    // Constructor privado
    S(object_ptr &&o, data_ptr &&d) :
        m_object{std::move(o)},
        m_data{std::move(d)}
    {};
};

int main()
{
    const auto &a = S<O, D>::create(std::tuple{'\0', short{1}, 2}, std::tuple{3l, .4f, .5});

    return 0;
}

Pero aún me parece verboso y desagradable explicitar std::tuple en S::create, puede verse el código funcionando aquí.

Separando cada paquete de parámetros en funciones diferentes:
Esta solución se basa en que una primera llamada construye el primer objeto, el cuál devuelve un objeto temporal con un operador de llamada (operator()) que construye el segundo objeto:
struct O { O(char, short, int) {} };
struct D { D(long, float, double) {} };

template <typename Object, typename Data>
class S
{
    using object_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Object>;
    using data_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Data>;

    struct TwoStepBuild
    {
        template <typename ... A>
        TwoStepBuild(object_ptr a_object) :
            m_object{std::move(a_object)}
        {}

        template <typename ... B>
        S operator()(const B &&... b) &&
        {
            return S(std::move(m_object), std::make_unique<Data>(b ...));
        }

        object_ptr m_object{};
    };

    object_ptr m_object{};
    data_ptr m_data{};

    // Constructor privado
    S(object_ptr &&o, data_ptr &&d) :
        m_object{std::move(o)},
        m_data{std::move(d)}
    {};

public:
    // Factoria
    template <typename ... A>
    static TwoStepBuild create(const A &&... a)
    {
        return {std::make_unique<Object>(a ...)};
    }
};

int main()
{
    const auto &a = S<O, D>::create('\0', short{1}, 2)(3l, .4f, .5);

    return 0;
}

Esta aproximación es mucho más limpia que las anteriores, pero su sintaxis puede resultar confusa. El código funcionando está disponible aquí.

En ambas aproximaciones escribes funciones de signatura const auto &&. ¿Por qué te limitas a r-value references en vez de recibir const auto & (que admite tanto l-values como r-values) o auto && (referencia universal)?

@JorgeLuis la verdad es que no hay ningún motivo sesudo detrás de ese uso de const auto &&, una referencia a valor de lado izquierdo constante no vale para nada ya que al ser constante no se podrá modificar y por lo tanto no se podrá mover. El motivo es que se me fue el dedo con el copia-pega.
